# Best initial guess for Newton-Raphson method to find a real root of the cubic polynomial

Tags: roots, cubics, newton-raphson

What initial guess to use for Newton-Raphson method to find a real root of the cubic polynomial
$$
x^3 + px^2 +qx +r
$$
so, that the Newton-Raphson method converges fast. It's given, the cubic polynomial has only one real root with high probability. Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need the Newton-Ralphson method when you have Cardano's formula?

Comment: @markvs. In real life, using Cardano, you may loose roots if you work with limited precision (even quadruple).

Answer (score 2):

Set $f(x)=x^3+px^2+qx+d$. If $f$ is monotonic, then N-R will work quickly, so assume $f$ admits a local max and min. Since $f$ has only one real root, the local extrema will either both be positive or both be negative, and they will occur at

\begin{align*}
x_{max}=\frac{-p-\sqrt{p^2-3q}}{3} &&\text{and}&& x_{min}=\frac{-p+\sqrt{p^2-3q}}{3}
\end{align*}

If both extrema are positive, choose an $x$-value less than $x_{max}$.

If both extrema are negative, choose an $x$-value greater than than $x_{min}$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to guess to find a good initial estimate. With bracketing methods, such as the [Newt-safe method](https://youtu.be/FD3BPTMGJds), it suffices to use [initial points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#Bounds_on_all_roots) $x_\mathrm L$ and $x_\mathrm R$ where $\operatorname{sign}(f(x_\mathrm L))\ne\operatorname{sign}(f(x_\mathrm R))$. Convergence is then guaranteed within this interval.

In this specific case, you can further improve upon the initial bounds by finding the local extrema as explained in [Bonnaduck's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4292414), or for example by inserting an initial estimate of the root between $x_\mathrm L$ and $x_\mathrm R$ that is likely closer than either of the bounds, such as $x_0=0$ or $x_0=-\sqrt[3]r$.